# How to run the Metacircular Evaluator in DrRacket

Tags: lisp, scheme, racket

I'm trying to run the program described in SICP 4.1 (http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-26.html) but have run into some difficulty in redefining the function `apply` as the book suggests that you do.  The code is the following:

```
 #lang planet neil/sicp

;; -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
;; 4.1.1 The Core of the Evaluator
;; -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

;; Eval
(define apply-in-underlying-scheme apply)
(define (eval exp env)
  (display 'eval)
  (newline)
  (display exp)
  (newline)
  (cond ((self-evaluating? exp) exp)
        ((variable? exp) (let ((res (lookup-variable-value exp env)))
                           (display (list 'lookup exp))
                           (newline)
                           (display res)
                           (newline)
                           res))
        ((quoted? exp) (text-of-quotation exp))
        ((assignment? exp) (eval-assignment exp env))
        ((definition? exp) (eval-definition exp env))
        ((if? exp) (eval-if exp env))
        ((lambda? exp)
         (make-procedure (lambda-parameters exp)
                         (lambda-body exp)
                         env))
        ((begin? exp)
         (eval-sequence (begin-actions exp) env))
        ((cond? exp) (eval (cond->if exp) env))
        ((application? exp)
         (apply (eval (operator exp) env)
                (list-of-values (operands exp) env)))
        (else
         (error "Unknown expression" exp))))

;; Apply

(define (apply procedure arguments)
  (display 'apply)
  (newline)
  (display procedure)
  (newline)
  (cond ((primitive-procedure? procedure)
         (apply-primitive-procedure procedure arguments))
        ((compound-procedure? procedure)
         (eval-sequence
          (procedure-body procedure)
          (extend-environment
           (procedure-parameters procedure)
           arguments
           (procedure-environment procedure))))
         (else
          (error
           "Unknown procedure type -- " procedure))))



;; Application

(define (application? exp) (pair? exp))
(define (operator exp) (car exp))
(define (operands exp) (cdr exp))

;; Procedure arguments

(define (list-of-values exps env)
  (if (no-operands? exps)
      '()
      (cons (eval (first-operand exps) env)
            (list-of-values (rest-operands exps) env))))

(define (no-operands? ops) (null? ops))
(define (first-operand ops) (car ops))
(define (rest-operands ops) (cdr ops))

;; Conditionals

(define (eval-if exp env)
  (if (true? (eval (if-predicate exp) env))
      (eval (if-consequent exp) env)
      (eval (if-alternative exp) env)))

;; Sequences

(define (eval-sequence exps env)
  (cond ((last-exp? exps) (eval (first-exp exps) env))
        (else (eval (first-exp exps) env)
              (eval-sequence (rest-exps exps) env))))

;; Assignments and definitions

(define (eval-assignment exp env)
  (set-variable-value! (assignment-variable exp)
                       (eval (assignment-value exp) env)
                       env)
  'ok)

(define (eval-definition exp env)
  (define-variable! (definition-variable exp)
                    (eval (definition-value exp) env)
                    env)
  'ok)

;; Representing Expressions

;; self evaluating := items, numbers

(define (self-evaluating? exp)
  (cond ((number? exp) true)
        ((string? exp) true)
        (else false)))

;; variables = symbol

(define (variable? exp) (symbol? exp))

;; (quote <text-of-quotation>)

(define (quoted? exp) (tagged-list? exp 'quote))

(define (text-of-quotation exp) (cadr exp))

(define (tagged-list? exp tag)
  (if (pair? exp)
      (eq? (car exp) tag)
      false))

;; (set! <var> <value>)

(define (assignment? exp)
  (tagged-list? exp 'set!))

(define (assignment-variable exp) (cadr exp))
(define (assignment-value exp) (caddr exp))

;; (define <var> <value>)
;; or
;; (define <var>
;;   (lambda (<parameter-1> ... <parameter-n>)
;;      <body>))
;; or
;; (define (<var> <parameter-1> ... <parameter-n>)
;;    <body>)

(define (definition? exp)
  (tagged-list? exp 'define))

(define (definition-variable exp)
  (if (symbol? (cadr exp))
      (cadr exp)
      (caadr exp)))

(define (definition-value exp)
  (if (symbol? (cadr exp))
      (caddr exp)
      (make-lambda (cdadr exp)   ;; formal params
                   (cddr exp)))) ;; body

;; lambda

(define (lambda? exp) (tagged-list? exp 'lambda))

(define (lambda-parameters exp) (cadr exp))
(define (lambda-body exp) (cddr exp))

;; constructor for lambda expression

(define (make-lambda parameters body)
  (cons 'lambda (cons parameters body)))

;; if

(define (if? exp) (tagged-list? exp 'if))
(define (if-predicate exp) (cadr exp))
(define (if-consequent exp) (caddr exp))
(define (if-alternative exp)
  (if (not (null? (caddr exp)))
      (cadddr exp)
      'false))

;; constructor to transform cond expressions to if expressions

(define (make-if predicate consequent alternative)
  (list 'if predicate consequent alternative))

;; begin

(define (begin? exp) (tagged-list? exp 'begin))
(define (begin-actions exp) (cdr exp))
(define (last-exp? seq) (null? (cdr seq)))
(define (first-exp seq) (car seq))
(define (rest-exps seq) (cdr seq))

;; sequence->exp

(define (sequence->exp seq)
  (cond ((null? seq) seq)
        ((last-exp? seq) (first-exp seq))
        (else (make-begin seq))))

(define (make-begin seq) (cons 'begin seq))

;; derived expressions

(define (cond? exp) (tagged-list? exp 'cond))

(define (cond-clauses exp) (cdr exp))

(define (cond-else-clause? clause)
  (eq? (cond-predicate clause) 'else))

(define (cond-predicate clause) (car clause))
(define (cond-actions clause) (cdr clause))

(define (cond->if exp)
  (expand-clauses (cond-clauses exp)))

(define (expand-clauses clauses)
  (if (null? clauses)
      'false
      (let ((first (car clauses))
            (rest (cdr clauses)))
        (if (cond-else-clause? first)
            (if (null? rest)
                (sequence->exp (cond-actions first))
                (error "ELSE clause isn't last -- COND->IF"
                       clauses))
            (make-if (cond-predicate first)
                     (sequence->exp (cond-actions first))
                     (expand-clauses rest))))))

;; Representing procedures

;; (apply-primitive-procedure <proc> <args>)
;; (primitive-procedure? <proc>)

(define (make-procedure parameters body env)
  (list 'procedure parameters body env))

(define (compound-procedure? p)
  (tagged-list? p 'procedure))

(define (procedure-parameters p) (cadr p))
(define (procedure-body p) (caddr p))
(define (procedure-environment p) (cadddr p))

;; Operations on Environments

;; env is nothing but a list of frames.
(define the-empty-environment '())

(define (enclosing-environment env) (cdr env))
(define (first-frame env) (car env))

;; each frames contains variables and values
(define (make-frame variables values)
  (cons variables values))

(define (frame-variables frame) (car frame))
(define (frame-values frame) (cdr frame))

(define (add-binding-to-frame! var val frame)
  (set-car! frame (cons var (car frame)))
  (set-cdr! frame (cons val (cdr frame))))

;; (extend-environment <variables> <values> <base-env>)

(define (extend-environment vars vals base-env)
  (if (= (length vars) (length vals))
      (cons (make-frame vars vals) base-env)
      (if (< (length vars) (length vals))
          (error "Too many arguments supplied" vars vals)
          (error "Too few arguments supplied" vars vals))))

;; (lookup-variable-value <var> <env>)

(define (lookup-variable-value var env)
  (define (env-loop env)
    (define (scan vars vals)
      (cond ((null? vars)
             (env-loop (enclosing-environment env)))
            ((eq? var (car vars))
             (car vals))
            (else (scan (cdr vars) (cdr vals)))))
    (if (eq? env the-empty-environment)
        (error "Unbound variable" var)
        (let ((frame (first-frame env)))
          (scan (frame-variables frame)
                (frame-values frame)))))
    (env-loop env))

;; (set-variable-value! <var> <value> <env>)

(define (set-variable-value! var val env)
  (define (env-loop env)
    (define (scan vars vals)
      (cond ((null? vars)
             (env-loop (enclosing-environment env)))
            ((eq? var (car vars))
             (set-car! vals val))
            (else (scan (cdr vars) (cdr vals)))))
    (if (eq? env the-empty-environment)
        (error "Unbound variable -- SET!" var)
        (let ((frame (first-frame env)))
          (scan (frame-variables frame)
                (frame-values frame)))))
  (env-loop env))

;; (define-variable! <var> <value> <env>)

(define (define-variable! var val env)
  (let ((frame (first-frame env)))
    (define (scan vars vals)
      (cond ((null? vars)
             (add-binding-to-frame! var val frame))
            ((eq? var (car vars))
             (set-car! vals val))
            (else (scan (cdr vars) (cdr vals)))))
    (scan (frame-variables frame)
          (frame-values frame))))

(define (true? x)
  (not (eq? x false)))

(define (false? x)
  (eq? x false))

;; -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
;; 4.1.4 - Running the Evaluator as a Program
;; -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

(define (primitive-procedure? proc)
  (tagged-list? proc 'primitive))

(define (primitive-implementation proc) (cadr proc))

(define primitive-procedures
  (list (list 'car car)
        (list 'cdr cdr)
        (list 'cons cons)
        (list 'null? null?)
        ))

(define (primitive-procedure-names)
  (map car
       primitive-procedures))

(define (primitive-procedure-objects)
  (map (lambda (proc) (list 'primitive (cadr proc)))
       primitive-procedures))

(define (apply-primitive-procedure proc args)
  (apply-in-underlying-scheme
   (primitive-implementation proc) args))

(define (setup-environment)
  (let ((initial-env
         (extend-environment (primitive-procedure-names)
                             (primitive-procedure-objects)
                             the-empty-environment)))
    (define-variable! 'true true initial-env)
    (define-variable! 'false false initial-env)
    initial-env))

;; for scheme, uncomment for lisp
;;(define true #t)
;;(define false #f)

(define input-prompt " mscheme > ")
(define output-prompt " .. ")

(define (driver-loop)
  (prompt-for-input input-prompt)
  (let ((input (read)))
    (let ((output (eval input the-global-environment)))
      (announce-output output-prompt)
      (user-print output)))
  (driver-loop))

(define (prompt-for-input string)
  (newline) (newline) (display string) (newline))

(define (announce-output string)
  (newline) (display string) (newline))

(define (user-print object)
  (if (compound-procedure? object)
      (display (list 'compound-procedure
                     (procedure-parameters object)
                     (procedure-body object)
                     '<procedure-env>))
      (display object)))

;; start repl
(define the-global-environment (setup-environment))
(driver-loop)
```

The problem is the beginning, where I am trying to save the scheme builtin apply as "apply-in-underlying-scheme."  Since there is another function named "apply" written below, I get the error "reference to an identifier before its definition: apply."  How can I reference the builtin "apply" without causing an error here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could just rename the function that SICP calls `apply` to `metacircular-apply` or something like that. There's no need for it to be called `apply` other than aesthetics.

Answer (score 1):

I use the following header, which renames apply to apply-in-underlying-scheme:

```
#!r6rs
(import (except (rnrs base) apply)
        (rnrs io simple)
        (rename (rnrs base) (apply apply-in-underlying-scheme))
        (rnrs mutable-pairs))
```

Answer (score 1):

While you can't redefine a definition in the Racket language `#lang racket` or similar, you can use the require feature of Racket's module system.

```
(require (only-in racket [apply apply-in-underlying-scheme]))
```

Here `only-in` means that only the bindings we specify will be loaded, here being `apply` from the built-in module `racket`.

We could also use `rename-in` instead of `only-in`, but since the `racket` module is always loaded as part of the racket language, we don't need to re-import all of it and thus just use `only-in`.